# Detect incognito mode in an content script

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a Firefox WebExtension and i would like to be able to detect if my content scripts are running in incognito/private mode or not. Is it possible ?

I already tried those solutions:

- Use `window.incognito` but it's undefined
- Get the current tab with `browser.tabs.getCurrent()` then access `Tab.incognito` but `browser.tabs` is undefined
- Use `extension.inIncognitoContext` but `extension` is not defined.

Is there another way to get this information ?
I'm running Firefox 50.1.0, my script is running as a content script and my manifest has those permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs) for this might not make this immediately obvious, but if you prefix `extension.inIncognitoContext` with `browser` or `chrome` it will work.

```
console.log(browser.extension.inIncognitoContext);
```