# Firefox extension needs to determine if it is in private browsing

Tags: incognito-mode

I'm trying to modify an old FireFox extension that was custom written by someone who is long gone (Firefox 50 -Please no comments about how old it is)

I need to add to the extension the ability to determine if it is in a regular browser window or a private window.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709369/detect-incognito-mode-in-an-content-script) I should be able to use `console.log(browser.extension.inIncognitoContext);`

When I try it in the web console, I get 'ReferenceError: browser is not defined'

I also found this [extension.inIncognitoContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/inIncognitoContext) but couldnt get `let isPrivate = browser.extension.inIncognitoContext;` to work either.

Some help getting my extension to determine browser mode woudld be appreciated. Either using above idea, or I saw in my searching there was mention (but no examples) of API's that extensions could use to determine browser mode.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only use `browser` from within an extension, not from the web console. Try writing a sample extension to run the code and log results to the console. [Here is a good walk-through of setting that up.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)

```
let isPrivate = browser.extension.inIncognitoContext;
console.log(isPrivate);
```

Alternatively, albeit a bit more convoluted:

```
function getState(window) {
  mode = window.incognito;
  console.log(mode);
}

browser.windows.getCurrent().then(getState);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**